# Source Control on Domino Designer: Files not getting deleted on on-disk project

Tags: xpages

A weird one here. I've noticed that the 'Team Development - Sync with On-Disk Project' is not deleting files on my ODP. I'm not using automatic updating.

I've looked at the permissions on the odp/nsf folder, and I've noticed a little grey out checkbox which I can remove, but it pops back up immediately.

I've also tried opening up the security on the folder (right-click/properties/Security) and giving most groups superpowers, but no bananas.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Update: **the deletions happen, but not immediately.** I'm confused.

Comment: Andrew, we have had issues not just with deletion but newly added files received via git, the only solution is to refresh both projects a few times and sync them both.

Comment: Samir, this was the solution. After a while I saw my files correctly deleted. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll set that as being the correct answer.

Comment: Added the answer as requested, glad this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have had issues not just with deletion but newly added files received via git, the only solution is to refresh both projects a few times and sync them both.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue: I often lose some project settings, i.e. an additional source folder and a .jar file. It probably has something to do with replication, but it's impossible for me to find out exactly why this is happening.

Comment: Forget replication if you use source control. It can cause some strange behaviour.

Comment: Can I un-use source control?

Comment: yes, you must remove the association with the On Disk Project, found in the Team menu item when you click on the project and right mouse click

Comment: Thanks, but there is no associated on-disk project any more. Still losing settings though... Also, I always have to use Project/Clean, in order to recompile everything correctly.

Comment: I hope your On Disk Project was not in the root of the git repository. The best way is create a folder (e.g. nsf ) in the root of the repository and put the ODP inside this new folder. Otherwise you will get very strange behaviour.

Comment: Frank, no it isn't. The problem corrected itself without me doing anything.

Comment: Have you setup ignore files in git for your project @D.Bugger? Best to create a new copy of the db, delete the other db and any associated on disk files (using package explorer view) and see if the same issue happens again without source control on the new copy.

Comment: No git, no nothing... Made a new replica, problem persists. Somehow, replication messes everything up (I think). The development database is also a test database, used by 2 people on 4 different servers. And only the Java Build Path in the Project Properties gets corrupted, everything else is OK. I always have to add one source folder and one JAR file... Sorry, Andrew, for misusing your question...

Comment: Why not place the JAR file on the server?